# How to use try catch in this code for checking my error

Tags: try-catch

I am a beginner in Programming. I want to make sure how to check my errors. In this code, I just write plus operation.

private void number2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
}                                       

private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    
    double a, b;
    a = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText());
    b = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText());
    result.setText("" + (a + b));
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try
    {
    double a, b;
    a = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText());
    b = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText());
    result.setText("" + (a + b));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
    }
}
```